# CSS How to Make Image Display outside of div

Tags: css, html, cut

I have an image that i would like to extend beyond the div and display outside of the border that is displayed.

Every time i try and move it, the top of the image just gets cut off. (See the ebook image at the top of the 2nd column...)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried absolutely positioning the image?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add all relevant parts of code (HTML, CSS …) to this question in order to make it self contained and that somebody can help you to improve your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the CSS rule:

```
.entry-content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Currently the property is being set to `hidden` which, as the name suggests, hides all content that extends outside of its bounds. Setting it to `visible` lets the content be shown.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: This is the right solution, but the default browser value is `visible`. The value is set explicitly in the *minified.css*.

Comment: Sorry, @insertusernamehere, you're right, I've probably gotten a little too used to using CSS resets that do this for me.

Comment: @user2541522 If this answer helped you, please use the big checkmark to accept it as a solution to you problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="entry-content">
```

The above code can be found via the chrome debugger. It's the container for your content boxes, including that image.

The entry-content class is currently set to `overflow:hidden`. Update that to `overflow:visible` or remove the `.entry-content` class from that div.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try out this line:

```
<img style="float: right; overflow: visible; margin: 15px 13px 0px 0px; display: inline" align="right" src="http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/assets/secret-new-ms.png">
```

Change the `margin: -30px 13px 0px 0px;`

to

```
margin: 15px 13px 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your image a margin: 10px. That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

change in "http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/prose/minified.css" file @ line 2
from

```
.entry-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.entry-content {
overflow: visible;
}
```

or add this rule in any css file

```
.entry-content {
overflow: visible !important;
}
```